# Understanding F# StringConstant

Tags: f#

I am trying to understand the following code, particularly StringConstant:

```
type StringConstant = StringConstant of string * string 

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let x = StringConstant("little", "shack")
    printfn "%A" x

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

(By way of context, StringConstant is used in the [FParsec tutorial](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html), but this example does not use FParsec.)

What I would like to know is:

1. what exactly is the type statement doing?
2. once I instantiate x, how would I access the individual "parts"
   ("little" or "house")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others already noted, technically, `StringConstant` is a discriminated union with just a single case and you can extract the value using pattern matching.

When talking about [domain modelling](http://tomasp.net/blog/type-first-development.aspx) in F#, I like to use another useful analogy. Often, you can start just by saying that some data type is a tuple:

```
type Person = string * int
```

This is really easy way to represent data, but the problem is that when you write `"Tomas", 42`, the compiler does not know that you mean `Person`, but instead understands it as `string * int` tuple. One-case discriminated unions are a really nice way to *name* your tuple:

```
type Person = Person of string * int
```

It might be a bit confusing that this is using the name `Person` twice - first as a type name and second as a name of the case. This has no special meaning - it simply means that the type will have the same name as the case.

Now you can write `Person("Tomas", 42)` to create a value and it will have a type `Person`. You can decompose it using `match` or `let`, but you can also easily write functions that take `Person`. For example, to return name, you can write:

```
let getName (Person(name, _)) =  
  name
```

I think single-case discriminated unions are often used mainly because they are really easy to define and really easy to work with. However, I would not use them in code that is exposed as a public API because they are a bit unusual and may be confusing.

PS: Also note that you need to use parentheses when extracting the values:

```
// Correct. Defines symbols 'name' and 'age'
let (Person(name, age)) = tomas 

// Incorrect! Defines a function `Person` that takes a tuple 
// (and hides the `Person` case of the discriminated union)
let Person(name, age) = tomas
```

Answer (score 2):

`StringConstant` is a discriminated union type, with just a single case (also named `StringConstant`).  You extract the parts via pattern matching, using `match`/`function` or even just `let`, since there is just a single case:

```
let (StringConstant(firstPart, secondPart)) = x
```

Comment: +1 (I had to delete the first paragraph from my work-in-progress answer, because it was exactly what you wrote :-))

Answer (score 1):

```
type StringConstant = StringConstant of string * string
```

results in a discriminated union with one type.

`type StringConstant = | StringConstant of string * string` if you execute it in F# interactive.

You can see the msdn documentation on that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx).

You can get the value out like this:

```
let printValue opt =
    match opt with
    | StringConstant( x, y) -> printfn "%A%A" x y
```

Answer (score 1):

The other guys already mentioned how you extract the data from a discriminated union, but to elaborate a little more on Discriminated unions one could say that they are sorta like enums on steroids. They are implemented behind the scenes as a type hierarchy where the type is the base class and the cases are subclases of that baseclass with whatever parameter they might have as readonly public variables.

In Scala a similar data-structure is called case classes which might help you convince yourself of this implementationmethod.

One nice property of discriminated unions are that they are self-referenceable and therefor are perfect for defining recursive structures like a tree. Below is a definition of a Hoffman coding tree in just three lines of code. Doing that in C# would probably take somewhere between 5 and 10 times as many lines of code.

```
type CodeTree =
     | Branch of CodeTree * CodeTree * list<char> * int
     | Leaf of char * int
```

For information about Discriminated Unions see the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx)

For an example of using Discriminated Unions as a tree-structure see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ssboisen/3889505#file-huffman-fs) which is an implementation of a huffman decoder in roughly 60 lines of F#)